# What if Jupiter and other gas planets suddenly disappear?

Tags: gas-giants

What will happen to us?

Jupiter, for example, take away comets from their path, so they will not hit earth.

What else can/cannot happen? Have they any purpose for us?

Comment: We wouldn't see the beautiful appearance of Jupiter in these days morning skies. Would be sad.

Comment: It will put astrologers out of a job. Which would be good.

Comment: 1) Absolutely nothing would happen. 2) Jupiter takes away only a negligible part of the asteroids (and it sends others inside the inner solar system).